# Error in voom(dge, design, plot = TRUE, normalize = "quantile") : Need at least two genes to fit a mean-variance trend

Tags: r, bioinformatics

My matrix `mat` has two groups, `C` and `D`, 4 samples per group, as denoted in the column names. I want to perform differential expression analysis.

First, I scaled the data before assigning the `groups` and `design`.

```
library(limma)

mat <- apply(mat, 2, \(x) {
  x <- as.numeric(x) 
  (x - min(x)) / diff(range(x))
})

group <- factor(as.factor(gsub("_.*", "", colnames(mat))), levels=c("C", "D"))
design <- model.matrix(~group)
colnames(design) <- c("C","CvsD")
```

Second step: Normalization and filtering

```
dge <- DGEList(counts=mat, group=group)
keep <- filterByExpr(dge, design)
dge <- calcNormFactors(dge[keep,,keep.lib.sizes=FALSE])
```

Third step: Differential expression

```
v <- voom(keep, design, plot=TRUE, normalize="quantile")
```

Traceback:

```
Error in voom(dge, design, plot = TRUE, normalize = "quantile") : 
  Need at least two genes to fit a mean-variance trend

fit <- eBayes(lmFit(v, design))
fit <- treat(fit, lfc=log2(1.2))
topTreat(fit, coef=ncol(design))
dt <- decideTests(tfit)
summary(dt)

> summary(dt)
       C - D
Down       0
NotSig     0
Up      1725
```

Data:

```
> dput(mat[1:10,])
structure(c(1.0275, 1.05, 0.55875, 0.78375, 0.7175, 0.76875, 
0.70875, 0.63, 0.73125, 0.76875, 0.8675, 0.74, 0.54875, 0.71375, 
0.6775, 0.64875, 0.61875, 0.63, 0.63125, 0.91875, 0.6775, 0.9, 
0.64875, 0.70375, 0.6975, 0.69875, 0.64875, 0.76, 0.65125, 0.82875, 
1.3075, 1.03, 0.81875, 1.06375, 0.8375, 0.91875, 0.99875, 1.03, 
0.98125, 1.05875, 0.7225, 0.89, 0.59125, 0.70625, 0.6925, 0.64125, 
0.63125, 0.64, 0.62875, 0.89125, 0.9625, 0.8, 0.60125, 0.77625, 
0.7325, 0.72125, 0.76125, 0.8, 0.75875, 0.78125, 1.2925, 1.05, 
0.75125, 0.91625, 0.8425, 0.86125, 0.86125, 0.83, 0.87875, 1.02125, 
0.9025, 0.98, 0.63125, 0.86625, 0.6625, 0.81125, 0.72125, 0.78, 
0.72875, 0.88125), dim = c(10L, 8L), dimnames = list(c("AAAS", 
"AAK1", "AAMDC", "AARS", "AASDHPPT", "ABCD3", "ABCE1", "ABCF1", 
"ABHD10", "ABI1"), c("C_1", "C_2", "C_3", "C_4", "D_5", "D_6", 
"D_7", "D_8")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Scaling your data kills any information on the magnitude of the counts and its mean-variance relationship and invalidates both the filterByExpr and the entire testing procedure. Omit that step and follow what is written in the limma user guide. Scaling is not part of it, not does it make sense for count data in this context. Use raw counts for voom as described in the manual. You should also make sure that the assay indeed produces digital counts which voom expects rather than anything else.

Answer (score 0):

**One Hint** :
Is to table the `filterByExpr` output before proceeding further.
In your provided data this dropped out all your matrix.

```r
table(keep)

keep
FALSE 
   10
```

**Second Hint** : is to check that you have count data

Comment: My `table(keep)` shows that all are false and the count data is 0 after `calcNormFactors`. But how can I rectify it?

Comment: Do you think that the scaling in the begging of your code is in-line with the further edgeR methods?